# Pandas on Docker FileNotFound

Tags: python, pandas, docker

I'm learning Python/TensorFlow and am running it in a docker container on a Mac. I am trying to access some data files in CSV that is stored locally on my host computer in the `my work` directory but get `FileNotFound` error when trying to access it.

I am using the file sharing facility in Docker Mac (which shares the `/Users` directory by default it seems) and trying to access the file that way in my Jupyter notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
incident = pd.read_csv('MyUserName\my work\incident.csv')
```

where `MyUsername` is my local user on my host. But the file is not found.

Comment: try.  `incident = pd.read_csv('/MyUserName/mywork/incident.csv') `

Comment: I did but get the following error: FileNotFoundError: File b'/xxxxxx/mywork/incident.csv' does not exist

Comment: Solved it. Corrected docker start command to: docker run -it --rm --name myTF -v /Users/myusername/mywork:/mywork -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-py3-jupyter  then in Jupyter was able to call "incidents = pd.read_csv('/mywork/incident.csv')"

Comment: awesome, I have added this as answer So, you can accept it to mark this as an answer for benefit of larger audience who are looking for same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution to read csv will be follows:

You need to choose forward slash `/`

```
incident = pd.read_csv('/MyUserName/mywork/incident.csv')
```